# Unknown JNDI Lookup String

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, jndi, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

I am new to EJB concept. I have seen the following in different website :

Sample 1:

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name="audit", beanInterface=AnotherEJBLocal.class)
public class EmployeeBean implements EmployeeServiceLocal, EmployeeServiceRemote {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EmployeeService")
  private EntityManager manager;

  public void doAction(){
    try {
      Context ctx = new InitialContext();
      AnotherEJBLocal audit = (AnotherEJBLocal) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/audit");
      audit.doAnother();
  } catch (NamingException e) {
      throw new EJBException(e);
  }

  }
}
```

Sample 2:

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

    EmployeeServiceRemote service = null;
    service = (EmployeeServiceRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("EmployeeBean/remote");


    service.doAction();



  }
```

Sample 3:

```
obj = ctx.lookup(ejb/CBDWebAppEAR/CBDWebApp.jar/<EJB name>/<Remote Interface Class Name>);
```

CBDWebApp is the project name in which the bean resides.

My question is:

1. What is the need & MEANING of java:comp/env/audit
2. Why same type of string is not used in case of Sample 2. I guess as
   it is a remote EJB not local.
3. Why is the meaning of the EJB look up string in the Sample 3.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `java:comp/env/audit` string is looking up the EJB reference that was declared earlier by the `@EJB(name="audit", beanInterface=AnotherEJBLocal.class)`.  Names declared by @EJB (and @Resource and all other EE references) are implicitly declared in the `java:comp/env` context.  With this reference, the deployer can retarget the "audit" reference to any EJB in the application that implements the AnotherEJBLocal interface, or if the deployer doesn't specify anything, the javadoc for the @EJB annotation requires it to target a single EJB within the same application that implements the interface.
2. This main method is (probably) declared by a standalone Java program.  In that case, it (probably) is configured via system properties to connect the JNDI server of an application server, which will return the remote reference to the client.  The name that is looked up is vendor-specific, and it was probably configured for the EJB during deployment.
3. This is very similar to #2, the only difference being the specific string being used.  In this case, it is probably relying on an application server's "default" binding name if none was configured for the EJB during deployment using the pattern `ejb/<app>/<module>/<bean>/<interface>`.